# Android - Unable to MUTE Audio in ChromeCast

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm implementing cast feature in one of my application and trying to mute the audio being cast from sender application to default receiver app.

Using "setStreamVolume()" api on RemoteMediaPlayer object to mute the audio, see below code:

```
remoteMediaPlayer.setStreamVolume(googleApiClient, 0).setResultCallback(
                    new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult( MediaChannelResult result) {
                            Status status = result.getStatus();
                            Log.d(TAG, "MUTE status:"+status);
                        }
                    });
```

But observed that, its returning 2100 (STATUS_FAILED) status code in result callback and not able mute the audio in receiver application.

Please suggest...

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest not using the Stream Volume but rather use the Device Volume. The corresponding mute method can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/Cast.CastApi.html#setMute(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20boolean)).

Comment: Thanks for your response... Observed that volume bar displayed every time when I use device volume methods like setMute(), setVolume(). I don't want to see those volume controls displayed every time mute/UN-mute event executed in chromecast, that is the reason I tried to use alternative ways using stream volume methods. 

Even I'm enthusiastic to know the reason behind 2100 failed status code, why stream volume methods not working, could you please tell me the reason for failure notice?

Comment: Without seeing your code, I am afraid I can't tell you why it is not working. why don't you want to see the volume bar on TV? It is a very useful UI feedback for the user who is changing the volume.

Comment: Client asking us to hide volume controls. That is the reason I'm trying different approaches to mute volume without displaying audio controls. 

Regarding the coding part, app don't have much complex code I'm instantiating RemoreMediaPlayer obj in joinApplication() methods connection result callback. Actually my app is joining to the YouTube cast session to control video/audio playback. Once I got success status code in connection result callback I'm identifying audio/video track in chrome-cast and applying mute/UN-mute events based on the event time codes available for that audio/video track.

Comment: I did another sample application by launching default receiver application, I mean used launchApplication() method and loaded some audio track in receiver. And executed setStreamVolume() method on RemoteMediaPlayer object, this time I got success response and I didn't see the audio icons when mute event executes. Which means setStreamVolume() won;t work if app join to another apps session, is that correct? or do we have another reason for the failure status.

Comment: If you are trying to control someone else's application (YouTube in this case), all bets are off; you cannot count on any of the standard/generic methods to be available to you.